# Can't run Xcode project on Simulator only with real device

Tags: ios, xcode

As you can see on the image I can't run my project on the simulator, it works only if I connect a real device. Before this issue I've reinstalled my Xcode, but it should work, because the simulator is at the developer tools and it works perfectly when I change the actual user of my mac book.

(The project uses proper provisioning profile).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 1

If you renamed Xcode.app since first launch, the iOS Simulator becomes unavailable. This is mentioned in the Xcode 6.1 Release Notes:

> Renaming Xcode.app after running any of the Xcode tools in that bundle may cause iOS Simulator to be no longer be available. Either rename Xcode.app back to what it was when first launched or restart your Mac. (16646772)

Try 2

Click to target or project > Build Settings > Architecture > Supported Platforms : change to iOS

Comment: I think the first option could be the problem, because iOS is my supported platform. However I didn't rename Xcode, I checked it in my application folder and it's Xcode. Is it possible that it has been renamed automatically somewhere else?

Comment: Try creating a new Project. If you experience the same Problem, Than delete the XCode Cleanly and Install it using the .dmg file

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that, because it's the second project that doesn't works.